# How to use some filters in angular-file-upload?

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

I use [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Module-API) to upload files in AngularJS.

And I have two filters, that I need to works together, I mean to allow user to upload only images and text files.

```
uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'imageFilter',
            fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
                var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
                return '|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp|gif|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
            }
        });

        uploader.filters.push({
            name: 'textFilter',
            fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
                var type = '|' + item.type.slice(item.type.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + '|';
                return '|txt|doc|docs|'.indexOf(type) !== -1;
            }
        });
```

In HTML code I use this like as:

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="uploader" multiple="" filters="imageFilter, textFilter">
```

But it works with logic `|OR|`, but I need with `|AND|`

Comment: Why dont you have one function and keep both the logic there and return the result?